# Sharepoint 2013 connecting to TFS 2013 - Error with Excel reports

Tags: excel, sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2013

We have upgraded TFS 2012 to TFS 2013 and did not have sharepoint installed before. So i installed tfs sharepoint components on a sharepoint server and tfs server and connected them. Everything is fine except excel reports and they give me the following error:

```
External Data Refresh Failed
The data connection uses Windows Authentication and user credentials could not be delegated. The following connections failed to refresh: TfsOlapReport
```

i have made sure Claims to windows authentication service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Browse to Central Administration in Sharepoint
2. Select Manage Service Applications
3. Select Secure Store Service (Type: Secure Store Service Application)
4. Under Manage Target Applications, Click on New
5. Enter Target Application ID = "TFS", Display Name = "TFS", Contact Email="Whatever", Target Application Type = "Group", Target Application Page URL = "None" and click Next
6. Do not enter anything on this page as it's asking for fields name and not the actual credentials.
7. Enter Target Application Administrators and Members and click ok.
8. it will take you back to the page that was displayed after performed step 3.
9. Now right click on "TFS" and select "Set Credentials" and then enter the username and password that this account will be running under.
10. Now login to the TFS Server and click extensions for Sharepoint products.
11. Select the sharepoint web application you are using.
12. Click Modify access.
13. Enter "TFS" under the Enterprise Application Definition field.
14. Also just to make sure "Excel Service applications are configured properly, Click on "Excel Service Application "Type: Excel Services Application Web Service Application".
15. Click on Trusted File Location and make sure the site collection is added to the Trusted File Location and location type is "Microsoft Sharepoint foundation". under Trust children check "children trusted". under Allow external data select "Trusted data connection libraries and embedded".
16. Go back to page displayed after step 14 and select "Global Settings".
17. File access method = "impersonation", Under Analysis Services EffectiveUserName, check "Use the EffectiveUserName property".
18. Check "Use an existing Unattended Service account" radio button and under Target Application ID: enter "TFS".
19. Also make sure under Trusted Data Providers, the providerid your excel application is using is listed.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error, please follow steps below which are quoted from this [blog](https://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/tfs-2010-sharepoint-2010-errors-when-showing-reports-in-dashboard/).

1. On the Team Foundation Server Administration Console, click Extensions for Sharepoint Products.
2. Select the Sharepoint Web Application which you are using.
3. Click Modify Access
4. Enter a user with access rights to the reports inside the Enterprise Application Definition field

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found the answer and i did try your steps but it's only 1/4 of the answer. i will list the steps in my answer.